# Facebook new permission SDK > 3.14.x

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

With the new SDK of Facebook, the permissions can be modified and if the user un-checks a permission and grants the rest and then I check to see in my app if all permissions are given and if some permissions aren't given then is there a way to reopen the session of the user with same permission?

Scenario:Hey I need your 'public_profile' and 'email' permissions

User: No, email permission for you!

MyApp: :(, tell the user, dude, I need your email permission and again direct him to facebookUI for signin.

User: User has already given me permission for his/her public_profile so he/she doesn't see the 'Info you provide' section and just sees the "Confirm" page and there he/she doesn't know that hey your permissions again don't have the email.

The workaround is to ask the user to delete the MyApp under his App settings and login again using FB, but this is bad user experience.

Any suggestions to have a way around this new permission?

Answer (score 1):

Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0#re-asking-declined-permissions and the section Re-asking declined permissions

Comment: Thanks! I used the - (void)
requestNewReadPermissions: (NSArray *)readPermissions
completionHandler: (FBSessionRequestPermissionResultHandler)handler;